# How can I generate a random hex color code using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, f-string

I am working on a Discord bot in python, and I need a way to generate a random hex color code, I looked it up online and I found this:

```
import random
color = "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
```

Is it possible to do the same thing using an f-string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import random
color = f"{"%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)}"
```

Is this what you want?

However, I don't think this is a good way to create a hex code. Personally, I would do it like this:

```py
import random
random_number = random.randint(0,16777215)
hex_number = str(hex(random_number))
hex_number ='#'+ hex_number[2:]
```

But that's just a preferance!

Comment: I have tried the top suggestion actually, and it doesn't generate a 6 digit one like I need, although I will test your other suggestion! Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, that solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped!

Comment: I actually just checked your profile and saw that you joined stack overflow on my birthday! (just find that a bit cool because you were also the first person to answer my first question)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use:

```
import random

color = f'{"%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)}'
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken (correct me if I am) but that is exactly what I did before, except that this time you just do f'{same exact code}'

Comment: Yes, as you are already generating an hex code and wanted to do it in the f string, which was your original question - doing it in the f string.

Comment: True, That is actually what I asked, Although what I really wanted to know was how do I do it without using the % formatting, but I didn't make that very clear, sorry for being rude, you were just trying to help and I didn't make what I needed very clear :)

Comment: No problem, make sure you try to create a title that actually represents your problem / questions, because people will try to answer the question in different ways. :)